# Is the range of a probability-valued random variable with the variation topology (almost) separable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be uncountable Polish spaces, $\Delta(Y)$ be the space of Borel probability measures on $Y$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the variation distance, and let $g:X\to \Delta(Y)$ be Borel measurable. Is $g(X)$ separable? I'm also interested in the weaker question of whether we can find for every Borel probability measure on $X$ a null set $N$ such that $g(X\setminus N)$ is separable.

Separable subspaces of $\Delta(Y)$ have a nice structure; they correspond exactly to subspaces of $L_1(\mu)$ for some Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $Y$. But the topology on all of $\Delta(Y)$ is extremely fine. For example, every set of Dirac measures is closed. My vague intuition is that it is so fine that functions with a nonseparable range cannot be Borel measurable.

Comment: Your problem seems in a way a bit similar to the one in [my first MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/54003). I have not thought anything of the possible details but maybe a solution could be obtained along [the same lines](https://mathoverflow.net/q/54531).

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful! Actually, there should be a simpler solutions since the domain here is Polish. I'll try to figure out the details.

Comment: @TaQ The answer there shows that for some null set $N$, the image $g(X\setminus N)$ is separable. The other answer would follow from the problem in Dudley's textbook, but I'm not sure how that problem works. There might be an implicit assumption that if $T$ is uncountable, then $2^T>2^\mathbb{N}=\mathfrak{c}$. This need not be the case.

Comment: Dudley has Problem 9 on page 387 where it is asked to show that *under the continuum hypothesis* the range of a Borel measurable map from a separable metric space to a metric space is separable. So, indeed, it seems that without that kind of additional assumption (or something alike) problem 10 on page 99 cannot be established.

Comment: @TaQ Thank you. Curiously, the second edition of the book has the same problem but is missing the assumption of CH.

Comment: [This MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/450521) and [this MO-answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/450522) are related to the gap in the above mentioned problem of Dudley.